# Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse . ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-studio, device-detection

I am getting the warning and Android Studio stops and keeps on processing but does nothing. I have attached my Samsung phone (KITKAT) but it does not show up anything at all.

I am getting the following WARNING message

```
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application  
using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse 
Restart ADB integration and try again 
Waiting for process: com.example.frkdeveloper.tictactoegsm`
```